Angular nested components undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')
I have a component that integrates another component depending on the content. The child component calls the parent component again as content.
Unfortunately I get the following error message and I don't know how to fix it:
main.ts:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')
The structure looks like this:

Content renderer

Content-Renderer-Type Headline

Content renderer

Content-Renderer.Type Text




Content-Renderer-Type Paragraph

Content-Renderer

Content-Renderer.Type Text







Renderer-Component:
<span *ngFor="let c of content">
    <app-content-headline *ngIf="c.type === 'heading'" [content]="c"></app-content-headline>
    <app-content-paragraph *ngIf="c.type === 'paragraph'" [content]="c"></app-content-paragraph>
    <app-content-list *ngIf="c.type === 'list'" [content]="c"></app-content-list>
    <app-content-text *ngIf="c.type === 'text'" [content]="c"></app-content-text>
</span>

Child-Component:
<p>
    <app-content-renderer *ngIf="content.children" [content]="content.children" />
</p>


Could you please share a stackblitz with the issue happening
